# VS 2013 Windows Store .. Media Element

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a windows store app and i'm trying to add a sound to the button for when you click it. I have my coding done, error free, but the sound does not play. 
Any help is appreciated.

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="Explore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163"        Margin="692,461,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="546" BorderThickness="0" Click="Explore_Click"/>

<MediaElement x:Name="suprise" Source="Assets/suprise.mp3" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="147" Margin="108,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="533" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
```

xaml.cs

```
private void Explore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Explore));
    suprise.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The MediaElement needs to be in the visual tree to play and will stop when it is removed. Since Explore_Click navigates away before surprise has played, surprise isn't able to play its sound.

You have a few options:

1. Let surprise finish before calling Frame.Navigate. The app can handle surprise's [MediaEnded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaended.aspx) event and navigate there.
2. Put surprise on the Explore page and play it when that page is reached
3. Use a global MediaElement in a page outside of the Frame containing the app's normal pages. This will let the MediaElement stay in the visual tree even as the app switches pages beneath it. This is generally needed if you want to play a consistent soundtrack during the app, but not so much for special effects. I discuss this method in more detail in my blog entry [Frame of reference: keeping the music playing across pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/04/24/frame-of-reference-keeping-the-music-playing-across-pages.aspx)

Comment: Still unable to get this working, I changed it so the surprise sound would play when u click the button before going to the other page and still nothing